# AmMaps MapImage appears on window resize/move after deleteObject() call on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, maps, amcharts

I need to show pulsar animation in the map point on an event. I add circle image to the map and remove it after some time. I animate the image using CSS. All works ok, but if I try to resize the window, the image appears again and is never removed after.

Here is the issue screencast:
[image]

See the [codepen](https://codepen.io/b2709f1b/pen/XZNWYM) (the event is illustrated using `setTimeout()`).

Am I using the wrong method for image deletion or missing smth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you're supposed to call `validateData()` or `validateNow()` on the entire map when adding new images. Since you're using `tap.validate()` to add a single image, you have to leverage some internal APIs similar to what was suggested in [this ticket](https://github.com/amcharts/ammap3/issues/22) to make that work. Using your code as a base:

```
  tap.validate();
  this.map.dataProvider.images.push(tap);
  // add to internal objects
  this.map.imagesProcessor.allObjects.push(tap);
  this.map.imagesProcessor.allSvgObjects.push(tap.displayObject);
  tap.parentArray = map.dataProvider.images;
  setTimeout(() => {
    tap.deleteObject();
  }, 1000);
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e39b5a8391e1de5bfab88274c12b2cf8/?editors=0010)